# Can GraphX be used to store, process, query and update large distributed graphs?

Tags: apache-spark

Can GraphX store, process, query and update large distributed graphs?

Does GraphX support these features or the data must be extracted from a Graph database source that will be subsequently processed by GraphX?

I want to avoid costs related to network communication and data movement.

Answer (score 1):

It can actually be done, albeit with a pretty complicated measures. MLnick from GraphFlow posted on titan mail group [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/aureliusgraphs/spark/aureliusgraphs/i72ZJG0yafg/AgH7pVstYTUJ) that he managed to use Spark 0.8 on Titan/Cassandra graph using FaunusVertex and TitanCassandraInputFormat, and that there was a problem in groovy 1.8.9 and newer Kryo version. 
In his GraphFlow [presentation](http://spark-summit.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Using-Spark-and-Shark-to-Power-a-Realt-time-Recommendation-and-Customer-Intelligence-Platform-Nick-Pentreath.pdf) in spark-summit, he seemed to have made the Titan/HBase over Spark 0.7.x works.

Or if you're savvy enough to implement the TitanInputFormat/TitanOutputFormat from Titan 0.5, perhaps you could keep us in the loop. And Titan developers said they do want to support Spark but haven't got the time/resources to do so.

Using Spark on Titan database is pretty much the only option I can think of regarding your question.

Answer (score 0):

Spark doesn't really have support in itself for long term storage yet, other than through HDFS(technically it doesn't need to run on HDFS but it is heavily integrated with it). So you could just store all the edges and vertices in files, but this is clearly not the most efficient way. Another option is to use a graph database like [neo4j](http://www.neo4j.org)

Comment: I read that Neo4j does not support distributed graph partitioning. Titan allows it, but Titan requires data conversion to HDFS, when OLAP operations are needed.

Comment: This results into data movement and network communication. Apache Spark can read from HDFS, HBase, Cassandra, and any Hadoop data source (Source: https://spark.apache.org/). So I would like to know if I can use OLAP operations in GraphX to persist the graph to an underlying data source like HBase or Cassandra.

Comment: @regispires honestly don't know that much about OLAP, or graph DBs, but I would say that storing the edges and vertices in anything spark has a connector to (Hbase, Cassandra) should be no problem, just look at the [examples](https://github.com/apache/spark/tree/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples)